# Find number of islands in a graph

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I implemented [number of islands](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/) and it solves the test cases but I get TLE upon submission. I think my solution is pretty straightforward and upon comparison, follows the logic of the official solution, except mine just breaks it into functions to reduce repetition. Could this be the issue or is it something else?

```
class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:

        from collections import deque
        
        queue = deque()
        islands = 0
        
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            for j in range(len(grid[0])):
                # find the start of the island
                if grid[i][j] == "1":
                    islands += 1
                    queue.append((i, j))
                    self.destroyIsland(grid, queue)
        return islands
                    
    def destroyIsland(self, grid, queue):
        directions = ((0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0))
        while queue:
            curr_m, curr_n = queue.popleft()
            
            grid[curr_m][curr_n] = "0"
    
            for direction in directions:
                self.validateBounds(curr_m + direction[0], curr_n + direction[1], grid, queue)
        
    def validateBounds(self, m, n, grid, queue):
        if m >= 0 and n >= 0 and m < len(grid) and n < len(grid[0]) and grid[m][n] == "1":
            queue.append((m, n))
```

Comment: You may want to run *cProfile* to see which ops. take more time than expected/needed and do fine-tune accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cell may be reachable from multiple directions, and thus may be put on the queue multiple times. After popping from the queue, you need to check if the cell still contains "1", because by that time, that cell may have been popped and explored already.
This bug could be found with the most basic debugging technique, print statements.

The following code works, with the check added. The rest is taken as-is from your question.

```
class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:

        from collections import deque
        
        queue = deque()
        islands = 0
        
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            for j in range(len(grid[0])):
                # find the start of the island
                if grid[i][j] == "1":
                    islands += 1
                    queue.append((i, j))
                    self.destroyIsland(grid, queue)
        return islands
                    
    def destroyIsland(self, grid, queue):
        directions = ((0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0))
        while queue:
            curr_m, curr_n = queue.popleft()
            # THIS IS YOUR BUG FIX
            if grid[curr_m][curr_n] == "0":
                continue
            
            grid[curr_m][curr_n] = "0"
    
            for direction in directions:
                self.validateBounds(curr_m + direction[0], curr_n + direction[1], grid, queue)
        
    def validateBounds(self, m, n, grid, queue):
        if m >= 0 and n >= 0 and m < len(grid) and n < len(grid[0]) and grid[m][n] == "1":
            queue.append((m, n))
```

That said, this runs in 797 ms, faster than 22.35% of overall solutions. My solution given below runs in 339 ms, faster than 87.50% of overall solutions.

```
class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        m = len(grid)
        n = len(grid[0])
        num_islands = 0
        
        for row in range(m):
            for col in range(n):
                if grid[row][col] == "1":
                    self.__bfs(grid, (row, col), m, n)
                    num_islands += 1
                
        return num_islands
        
    def __bfs(self, grid: list[list[str]], start: tuple[int, int], m: int, n: int) -> None:
        queue = collections.deque(iterable=[start]) 
        
        while queue:
            row, col = queue.popleft()
            if grid[row][col] != "1":
                continue
            grid[row][col] = "0"
            neighbors = [(row - 1, col), (row, col - 1), (row, col + 1), (row + 1, col)]
            for r, c in filter(lambda x: 0 <= x[0] < m and 0 <= x[1] < n and grid[x[0]][x[1]] == "1", neighbors):
                queue.append((r, c))
```